# backbone relational: one-to-one relationship where both entities have the same id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, one-to-one, backbone-relational

My attempt at defining a one-to-one relationship using backbone relational.

`B` is defined without any dependencies or knowledge of A

```
var B = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    /* No relationship defined with A */

});
```

`A` is then defined, with an attempt to define a one-to-one relationship to `B`.

```
var A = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    relations: [

        {

            type: Backbone.HasOne,

            key: 'b',

            relatedModel: B,

            reverseRelation: {

                key: 'a',

                type: Backbone.HasOne

            }

        }]

    /* ... */

});
```

The backbone relational documentation has this to say about one-to-one relationships:

```
The default reverseRelation.type for a "HasOne" relation is "HasMany". This can be set to "HasOne" instead, to create a one-to-one relation.
```

Inspecting the results of this indicates that when I do

```
var someId = 123;

var myB = B.findOrCreate(someId);

var myA = A.findOrCreate(someId);
```

Both objects `myA` and `myB` are created successfully, with all the expected data.

The related object, however is not there. I want `myA.b` to reference `myB`, and it appears that backbone relational has created this key but lefty it undefined.

I have not specified that the "join" is meant to happen using the `id` attributes of both classes - however I cannot figure out how.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: When you define `A`. `B` will be undefined. Try moving the relations to the definition of `B`. (relatedModel: B)

Comment: Or it seems that you can string B and that should do it. `relatedModel : 'B'`

Comment: @NULL I have updated the question - turns out that I was actually defining B before I was defining A, so this was not the problem... But I still do not know how to specify that `id` should be used as the relationship.